# Vue and Laravel Form Validation not returning 422 response

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, validation, vue.js

I'm trying to validate form data on the backend with Laravel and Vue, but I'm not getting the 422 response.

This is in my controller function:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required'
    ]);

    $location = $request->isMethod('put') ? 
    Locations::findOrFail($request->id) : new Locations;

    $location->id = $request->input('id');
    $location->name = $request->input('name');
    $location->address = $request->input('address');
    $location->city = $request->input('city');
    $location->state = $request->input('state');
    $location->zip = $request->input('zip');
    $location->phone = $request->input('phone');

    if($location->save())
    {
        return new LocationsResource($location);
    }
```

Here is the Vue method:

```
addLocation() {
if (this.edit === false) {
        // Add
        fetch('api/location', {
          method: 'post',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.location),
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.clearForm();
            alert('Location Added');
            this.fetchArticles();
          });

      } else {
        // Update
        fetch('api/location', {
          method: 'put',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.location),
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.clearForm();
            alert('Locations Updated');
            this.fetchArticles();
          })

      }
      }
```

Here is the form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="addLocation" class="mb-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" v-model="location.name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" v-model="location.city">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State" v-model="location.state">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Save</button>
</form>
```

When I open up the inspector and go into Network->XHR I get all the correct status codes back for CRUD, however when the form is supposed to fail I do not get back 422 HTTP status code.  When I submit the form with no data, it doesnt save, but no status code gets sent, there is no response to give feedback to the user.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: what does your response say in XHR?

Comment: When I click save and intentionally fail validation, nothing happens, I get no response, no feedback.

Comment: how could you say 'validation fails' if there is no response?

Answer (score 3):

I had to add "accept": "application/json" to the header of the addLocation method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required'
    ]);
```

I've never seen such usage. I don't think controller have the validate function. Try this:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required',
    'state' => 'required'
    ]);
```

Comment: I just checked and yes there is a usage like that coming from ValidateRequest trait but there is no any exception thrown at that function. It just returns an array of unvalidated fields. See; https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html#method_validate

Comment: I made the change but still same result.  Actually I do get a status of 302, type text/html when I click save.  Shouldnt I get 422?  Does it have anything to do with v-model="location.name" on the form but I only reference "name" in the controller?

Comment: and that is probably because of adding id field to new model instance. do not use any id modificaiton in your laravel model instance, let framework handle itself. i mean, use the id just for findOrFail method.

Comment: Can you clone this project and try to add backend validation to it?  https://github.com/bradtraversy/larticles_vue_app  I tried and get a 302 instead of 422

Answer (score 0):

The following code what i have tried

```
 const form_data = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form_data'));
 fetch("{{route('url')}}", {
       'method': 'post',
       body: form_data,
 }).then(async response => {
      if (response.ok) {
         window.location.reload();
      }
      const errors = await response.json();
      var html = '<ul>';
      for (let [key, error] of Object.entries(errors)) {
          for (e in error) {
              html += `<li>${error[e]}</li>`;
          }
      }
      html += '</ul>';
      //append html to some div

      throw new Error("error");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
  });
```

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;//Use at top of the page
$rules = [
    'file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',
    'field1' => 'required',
    'field2' => 'required'
   ];
$validator = Validator::make($request->post(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
}
session()->flash('flahs', ['status' => 'status', 'message' => 'message']);
```